No Bootable Devices Found after deleting and recreating fat32 and linux-swap partitions to increase size of /home partition
I have a Dell G15 laptop with one factory OS already installed Windows 11 and I installed Pop OS more or less 1 hear and 6 months ago in dual boot with the default Windows. I was with only 10GB of free space remaining in my /home (/dev/nvme0n1p10) partition and with approximately 84GB available in root (/) partition (/dev/nvme0n1p4) and because it I had to increase the /home partition. Before in GParted, the fat32 and linux-swap partitions were positioned between my root and /home partitions letting me impossible to increase the /home partition.
So I decided to recreate at the unallocated partition after ntfs (Windows 11 partition) the fat32 and linux-swap partitions with their same disk sizes and same flags as set before and I deleted these fat32 and linux-swap partitions accidentally positioned between /dev/nvme0n1p4 and /dev/nvme0n1p10, but after it, now looks like that Pop OS isn't booting anymore and when I press F12 (boot options) and choose Pop OS to initialize it shows: No Bootable Devices Found.
Here is the situation of my GParted now at Live Pop OS!:

Content from sudo fdisk -l:
pop-os@pop-os:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.53 GiB, 2721042432 bytes, 5314536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SM2P41C3 NVMe ADATA 512GB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3BC9EE5F-3870-46CD-845F-7768551C6227

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     411647    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     411648     673791    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     673792  325117951 324444160 154.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4  340185088  606425087 266240000   127G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5  954554368  956581887   2027520   990M Windows recovery environme
/dev/nvme0n1p6  956581888  997269503  40687616  19.4G Windows recovery environme
/dev/nvme0n1p7  997271552 1000214527   2942976   1.4G Windows recovery environme
/dev/nvme0n1p10 606425088  954548223 348123136   166G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p11 325117952  327215103   2097152     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p12 327215104  335603711   8388608     4G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: M3 Portable     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3ac1ed18

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       64 1953520064 1953520001 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 57.67 GiB, 61920509952 bytes, 120938496 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9c983c2b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048 120872959 120870912 57.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       120872960 120938495     65536   32M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/mapper/ventoy: 2.85 GiB, 3064233984 bytes, 5984832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6054dafc

Device                   Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/ventoy-part1 *        0 5984831 5984832  2.9G  0 Empty
/dev/mapper/ventoy-part2        488    8679    8192    4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/zram0: 15.31 GiB, 16438525952 bytes, 4013312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Procedures that I already done at Pop OS Live USB:

Execution of the boot repair tool with the option: Recommended Repair
/dev/nvme0n1p4 and /dev/nvme0n1p10 check about any problem and posterior fix
Try to change secure boot as disabled but it already set as disabled before
Compared values partuuid/GUID from efibootmgr and partuuis in lsblk

But nothing of these above options worked
Now I would like what I should do to boot again Pop OS? I was searching about any fix but from my case but it's being hard to find which is about disk resize and I am very stucked and agonized with it.

You should only have one ESP (per device or drive). And all systems then install boot loaders into separate folders in that ESP. If you deleted an ESP, you updated GUID/partUUID. UEFI uses GUID to find ESP to boot from. Compare sudo efibootmgr -v to lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid You need to reinstall boot loader. Do not know details on reinstall of SystemD boot, but if grub you can use Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  or https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-boot requires chroot.

So the ESP would be the partition responsible for boot load the system isn't it? Now I figure why I can`t able to boot load my Pop OS! partition in various ways! I am gonna reinstall my boot loader so, boot repair I already used this tool but the issue still persists here, but I am gonna give another try... about these commands sudo efibootmgr -v and lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid is to me check if the results fit with each other?

Another question is if should I delete again the fat32 and linux-swap partitions that I recreated between ntfs and unallocated and shrink nvme0n1p4 a little to recreate them again between nvme0n1p4 and nvme0n1p10 as before?

with lsblk -e... command my vfat partition nvme0n1p11 is different from the Windows one nvme0n1p1 because it isn't labeled as ESP, and in boot order the order is:
BootOrder: 0006,0005,0007,0002,0003,0009,0004,0000,0001,0008 where the 0006, 0005, 0007 and 0002 are respectively: Linux Firmware Updater, Pop!_OS, Windows Boot Manager and UEFI HTTPs Boot

You need to compare partuuid/GUID from efibootmgr -v & lsblk with partuuis. Default does not include partuuid.Most with Pop OS use systemD boot, not grub, so do you want grub installed? Not sure if systemd uses in ESP.

Finally I was able to solve this issue!! I followed here this tutorial: support.system76.com/articles/bootloader for my OS which is Pop OS at UEFI mode, I didn't have idea before that it's about the boot loader and the ESP EFI file that is responsible for boot the OS! and I saw that the values from the Linux Boot Manager at efibootmgr (partuuid) and in lsblk from the ESP EFI partition should be the same to work!!
